# Multiple roots of polynomials over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> 1. Show that $x^4+x+1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ does not have any multiple zeros in any field extension of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
> 2. Show that $x^{21} + 2x^8 +1$ does not have multiple zeros in any extension of $\mathbb{Z}_3$.
> 3. Show that $x^{21} + 2x^9 +1$  has multiple zeros in some extension of $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

These are three similar problems on field extensions. Can anybody help me please - how can I solve this type of problem? I am learning about field extensions on my own, so my ideas are not very clear. Please help.

Comment: Zev's answer is the definitive tool. A hint for a different approach to #3:
$$x^{21}+2x^9+1=(x^7+2x^3+1)^3.$$ Verify this by hand, if you haven't seen things like this before. One of the wonders of characteristic $p$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Given a field $K$ and some $f\in K[x]$, then $f$ has multiple roots (when considered over $\overline{K}$, an algebraic closure of $K$) if and only if $\gcd(f,f')\neq 1$, where $f'$ is the formal derivative of $f$.

This is mentioned in the [Wikipedia page on "separable polynomial"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_polynomial).

Comment: I know the result but could not apply it as they said-"does not have any multiple zeros in any field extension"

Comment: If it had multiple roots in any given field extension of $K$, it would necessarily have multiple roots in the algebraic closure of $K$.